Psalm 119:89 - What is the "word"?
Psalm 119:89 ESV
89 Forever, O LORD, your word
is firmly fixed in the heavens.
In Hebrew, the word for "word", is דְּ֝בָרְךָ֗ (ḏəḇārəḵā), from the word דָּבָר (dabar).
Swete's LXX shows the following:
Εἰς τὸν αἰῶνα, Κύριε, ὁ λόγος σου διαμένει ἐν τῷ οὐρανῷ.
Here is the commonly known term "logos".
The question I have is:
What is the nature of this "word"?

Is it the written words of the Bible, as is commonly believed among Evangelicals, at least in my experience?
Is it the Word of YHWH that came to various prophets in the Hebrew Scriptures, including men like Abraham (See, e.g. Genesis 15:1) and Jeremiah (See, e.g. Jeremiah 1:4)?
Is it the Pre-Incarnate Logos of John's Prologue, considering the LXX version?
Some combination of all of the above?
None of the above/Something else?


Have you examined the standard lexicons such as: https://biblehub.com/hebrew/1697.htm

Under the auspices of the Sanhedrin, the translators of the LXX chose the word, logos, which represents a conceptual snapshot of the what they thought the Hebrew word meant about 200+ years before Christ. Later, Jesus became known as the Word [Logos] of God incarnate. While, I don't believe that David had the Messiah in mind originally when one considers the context with the verses that followed, but this concept appears several times in the New Testament, culminating in Revelation 19:13 ESV: "He is clothed in a robe dipped in blood, and the name by which he is called is The Word of God."

The whole of Psalm 119 is clearly in praise of the Law of God. The prime referent of "word" would then be the Law. Other scriptures can reasonably be included too, but not even Christians should see this as referring to the Word incarnate.

My translation after my attempt by the LXX text (Psalm 118,89-96)
ιβ΄ λαβδ.
Eternally, O Lord, your word remains in the heaven! Into generation to other generation your honesty (is confirmed); you founded the earth, and it remains. In your classification the day remains, for everything is your own servant. If there was not the fact that your Law is my quest, then I would be lost, humiliating myself. Never in my life I will forget any of your rightfulls, for with them you have kept me in life, O Lord! I am yours, save me, because your rightfulls I have seek to do! The sinners had against me an attitude of persistence to destroy me (or kill me); I learned the lesson from your testimonies. I have seen the termination of every completed project; your commandment has a great foundation!
My translation after my attempt by the Hebrew text (Psalm 119,89-96)
ל Lamed
Eternally, O Lord, your word remains in the heaven! Into generation to other generation your faithfulness (is confirmed); you founded the earth, and it remains. In your classifications the day remains, for everything is your servant. If there was not the fact that your Law is my quest, then I would be lost, humiliating myself. Never in my life I will forget any of your rightfulls, for with them you have kept me in life, O Lord! I am yours, (please,) make to be saved myself, because your rightfulls I have seek to do! The sinners had against me an attitude of persistence to destroy me (or kill me); I will learn the lesson from your testimonies. I have seen the termination of every perfect (or completed) project; your command has a great foundation!
Conclusion
I believe that the "word" (דָּבָר › dabhárh), has to do with the word of God that has a foundation, and has come from the mouth of God to men, which guides, teaches, gives education, perhaps also prophecies, commands, righteous decisions, and the Law in general, etc. All these are embodied in this word of God. It does not, I think, make reference as the Word (Son of God) in this psalm. Of course, all of these things  consists the Word, but, specifically, it refers to the speech of God, which is consisted all of these things.
